# student and teacher and course relationships in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

### I have a problem with the relationships in my project in Laravel:

---

**My project consists of:**

- Student (ID- Name - Mobile - Email)
- Teacher (ID - Name - Mobile - Email)
- Course (ID - Name - description)

---

**Relationships :**

- Each course is offered by one or more teachers.
- Each teacher offers one or more courses.
- Each student enrolled in one or more courses.
- Each student attended one or more courses at one teacher

---

**Clarification :**

- course & teacher = (Many To Many).
- course & student = (Many To Many).
- student & teacher = (Many To Many).

---

**Through my search I found:**
Next two images .. Are these relationships true?

[image]

[image]

---

---

**My Work:**

**- migrations:**

```
Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');

            $table->timestamps();
        });


Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('mobile');
            $table->string('email');

            $table->timestamps();
        });


Schema::create('teachers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('mobile');
            $table->string('email');

            $table->timestamps();
        });


Schema::create('enrollments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('course_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });


Schema::create('teaches', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('course_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('teacher_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('teacher_id')->references('id')->on('teachers')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });


Schema::create('student_course_teacher', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('enroll_student_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('enroll_course_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('teach_teacher_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('enroll_student_id')->references('student_id')->on('enrollments')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('enroll_course_id')->references('course_id')->on('enrollments')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('teach_teacher_id')->references('teacher_id')->on('teaches')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

---

**- models:**

**- Course:**

```
class Course extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'courses';

    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class, 'enrollments', 'student_id', 'course_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function teachers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class, 'teaches', 'teacher_id', 'course_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**- Student:**

```
class Student extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'students';

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'enrollments', 'course_id', 'student_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**- Teacher:**

```
class Teacher extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'teachers';

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'teaches', 'course_id', 'teacher_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**- Enrollment:**

```
class Enrollment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'enrollments';

}
```

**- Teach:**

```
class Teach extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'teaches';

}
```

**Caution:** I can not make relationships in (**Enrollment** & **Teach**).

**My Requests:**

- Complete relationships
- I want to get students for a certain course with teacher information.
- I want to take courses with her students and teachers.
- I want to get certain teacher courses with students.

Waiting for help,,

Comment: It seems you haven't even tried to work through this:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @Devon: Check the question again .. I have written my code

Comment: Not sure what your question is.  You don't need models for Teach and Enrollment since those are pivot tables.

Comment: @Devon : Can you correct relationships? Well I want to work queries
Which I mentioned in the last question

Comment: No... because you haven't stated what's wrong with them.  SO isn't for code review, it's for specific problems and answers.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @netonline If, and only if, your code is working correctly and you are looking to improve it, I can suggest to post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of here.

Comment: @Devon : See the attached picture here
https://i.imgur.com/lBJp5UQ.png
The course is added to the student in the enrollments table, but is not added to the student_course_teacher table

Comment: @Phrancis : My code has not been completed and has not been working correctly until now .. There is a shortage .. and problems ..

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously not tested, but should help you figure out a solution towards your problem.

**Name Of Tables**

1. courses (For Course Model)
2. students (For Student Model)
3. teachers (For Teacher Model)
4. course_student (For Many To Many Relation between Student & Course) - For this you will create an extra model (CourseStudent), which will actually be used for Point 6.
5. course_teacher (For Many To Many Relation between Teacher & Course)
6. course_student_teacher (For Many To Many Relation between CourseStudent & Teacher)

**Models**

*Course Model*

```
class Course extends Model
{
  public function students()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class)->withTimestamps();
  }

  public function teachers()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class)->withTimestamps();
  }
}
```

*Students Model*

```
class Student extends Model
{
  public function courses()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class)->withTimestamps();
  }
}
```

*Teachers Model*

```
class Teacher extends Model
{
  public function courses()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class)->withTimestamps();
  }

  // Courses/Students Currently Being Taught
  public function courseStudents()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(CourseStudent::class, 'course_student_teacher')
                ->withTimestamps();
  }

  // List Of Students Currently Taught For Different Courses
  public function allStudentsCurrentlyTaught()
  {
    return $this->courseStudents()->get()->map(function($courseStudent) {
      return $courseStudent->student;
    })->unique('id');
  }

  // List Of Courses Currently Taught To Different Students
  public function coursesCurrentlyTaughtToStudents()
  {
    return $this->courseStudents()->get()->map(function($courseStudent) {
      return $courseStudent->course;
    })->unique('id');
  }

  // List Of Courses Taught To A Particular Students
  public function coursesTaughtToAStudent($studentId)
  {
    return $this->courseStudents()->get()->where('student_id', $studentId)->map(function($courseStudent) {
      return $courseStudent->course;
    });
  }

  // List Of Students Taught For A Particular Course
  public function coursesTaughtForACourse($courseId)
  {
    return $this->courseStudents()->get()->where('course_id', $courseId)->map(function($courseStudent) {
      return $courseStudent->course;
    });
  }
}
```

*CourseStudent Model* for creating pivot table `course_student_teacher`

```
class CourseStudent extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'course_student';

  public function course()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class)->withTimestamps();
  }

  public function student()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class)->withTimestamps();
  }

  public function teachers()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class, 'course_student_teacher')->withTimestamps();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i don`t know to use: in (Teacher Model) => **students**, **coursesCurrentlyTaughtToStudents**, **coursesTaughtToAStudent**, **coursesTaughtForACourse**, can you give me examples of their use .. please

Comment: prateekkathal : can u give me examples for their use .. please

Comment: @netonline From what I understand, your project will be having a *many to many* relation with **StudentCourse & Teacher**. So, those functions will go into the `course_student_teacher` table (which is the relational table between StudentCourse & Teacher) and then the collection functions will help you filter out records to get things like "Students Currently Taught By That Teacher" or "Courses That Are Currently Being Taught By Teacher". Please try and creating tables using Laravel conventions & then test these relations. You will only get a better understanding thereafter. Thanks. :)